# Convert a date format as text - day month

Tags: sql-server, impala

Insert a column: `received_by` as text in the format of Day Month.

i.e. **25/06/2018** should be inserted as **25 June**. The format `dd/mm/yyyy` should be converted into day month - whereby month should be written out.

Comment: `select convert(varchar(2),datepart(day, getdate())) + ' ' + datename(month, getdate())`

Comment: Dale Burrell & John Cappelletti 's replys are answer , there is the online test link [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=53d07662100a2bbadf03139e14599006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below select statement to get the desired return

```
select FORMAT(convert(datetime, '25/06/2018', 103), 'dd MMMM')
```

Or You can create the custom function in SQL server which will take a date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format and return day and month as required. use below code to achieve the desired result.

```
create function GetDateDaynMonth(@date varchar(20))
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @DaynMonth varchar (20)
SELECT @DaynMonth = FORMAT (convert(datetime, @date, 103), 'dd MMMM') 
return @DaynMonth;
end
go

select dbo.GetDateDaynMonth('25/06/2018')
```